# « comme peau de chagrin »: Does an amount decrease rapidly, or slowly but surely?

Tags: sens, usage

> Mon temps de loisir s'amenuise **comme peau de chagrin** : le travail empiète sur mon week-end, je me toque de vouloir reprendre le sport, et voilà que mes enfants jalousent ma MAC !

D'habitude, j’utilise « comme (une) peau de chagrin » pour decrire quelque chose dont la quantité diminue **doucement** mais sûrement, et ce éventuellement jusqu'à ce qu'il n'y en ait plus qu'un tout petit peu.

Mais je me demande si cette expression n‘insisterait pas, au contraire, sur la **rapidité** avec laquelle il se réduit progressivement ?

Soit dit en passant, s'emploie-t-elle plus couramment sans l’article indéfini « une » devant le nom « peau » qu’avec ?

Comment: Je pense qu'il n'y a pas de notion de rapidité, seulement une notion d’inéluctabilité.

Comment: @Toto Hi. S'il faut choisir l'un ou l'autre, penches-tu pour « se réduire ***peu à peu*** » ou « se réduire ***rapidement*** » ?

Comment: je suis d'accord avec Toto, c'est plutôt "inéluctablement" ou "irréversiblement"

Comment: l'omission de "une" relève de la licence poétique ou du procédé littéraire. L'article est (en théorie) obligatoire.

Comment: À choisir, je penche pour « se réduire *peu à peu* »

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Un roman d'Honoré de Balzac justement nommé *[La peau de chagrin](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Peau_de_chagrin)*, 1831, a crée cette expression.

*[Chagrin](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chagrin_(cuir))* signifie ici étymologiquement cuir, vraisemblablement du turc *sağrı*.

Il s'agit dans le roman d'une peau magique qui, un peu comme la lampe d'Aladin, exauce les vœux de son propriétaire. Malheureusement pour ce dernier, sa propre vie et la taille de la peau sont réduits au fur et à mesure des vœux successifs.

Il n'y a donc pas de notion de rapidité mais bien d'inéluctabilité de la réduction qui se poursuit jusqu'à la disparition totale.

L'omission de l'article après *comme* se rencontre parfois dans des expressions toutes faites comme par exemple:

- S'entendre comme larrons en foire
- Être comme cul et chemise
- Bête comme chou

Answer (score 4):

À mon sens, il n'y a pas de notion de rapidité, seulement une notion d’inéluctabilité.

Par conséquent, à choisir entre « se réduire **peu à peu** » ou « se réduire **rapidement** », c'est la première option qui me semble correcte.

« Se réduire **peu à peu** », éventuellement jusqu'à une disparition complète.

Comment: Voir aussi [_TLFi_](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chagrin), la _disparition complète_ est partie intégrante de l'allusion. Merci !

Comment: Quand l'essence est en train de se réduire comme peau de chagrin, est-ce qu’on va ***forcément*** finir par tomber en panne sèche ?

Comment: @Alone-zee: Oui, nécessairement. À moins que tu remplisses à temps le réservoir.

Comment: s'il se réduit comme peau de chagrin, il n'y a rien à faire: ce sera la panne sèche